# issue with Fetching data from Neo4j into the Mahout Data Model

Tags: neo4j, mahout, mahout-recommender

I am trying to implement a recommender using Mahout. My source database is a Neo4j graph database and I am able to fetch {userId,itemId,rates} values from it. However I do not know how to feed this input to Mahout to create a DataModel.
Should I implement a Neo4jJdbcDataModel just like what we have for MySQL?
I am a little bit confused so any hint would be appreciated.

P.S one workaround is to fetch data from Neo4j and save in into a csv and then feed the csv path to Mahout FileDataModel class. But this is a time consuming thing !! Specially when you have a large dataset !

Comment: not an answer, but why don't you use Neo4j directly for doing recommondations? Either with Cypher directly as sketched in http://graphgist.neo4j.com/#!/gists/3bf3a8e77dd53fe2a87c71e000311d99/summary or use Graphaware's framework https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-reco.

Comment: Well, the requirement is to use Mahout for Collaborative Filtering . For other custom queries like recommending the top sell item of a category, I am using the cypher itself. But for CLF I need to use Mahout .